# How can I attack this mySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I need to combine two tables.

The first table is People(SSN PRIMARY KEY, fname, lname).

The other table is Cities(name, cityID), where name = "fname lname" i.e. 2 columns of People concatenated with a space between. One person may have multiple cities associated with them, and a city may have more than one person (many - many).

I want to combine the two into a table PeopleCities(SSN, cityID). If no person is found for a city, I need SSN to be 0 for that cityID. My experience is mostly with sqlite rather than mySQL, so I'm not very confident in my query.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT ISNULL(People.SSN, 0), Cities.cityID
FROM People 
FULL OUTER JOIN Cities
ON (Cities.name = CONCAT_WS(" ", People.fname, " ", People.lname) FROM People);
```

Comment: You really need to restructure your data. Try and adhere to the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule)
of proper [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) or writing queries will be a lot more difficult. Why can't you reference by an ID field instead of a name? [People change names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and your database will be out of sync as soon as that happens.

Comment: It seems strange that no person would be found, if the city table has a `name` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`, first to get the people/city pairs that match and then to get the non-matches:

```
select p.ssn, coalesce(c.cityid, 0)
from people p left join
     cities c
     on c.name = concat_ws(' ', p.name, p.lname)
union all
select distinct 0, c.cityid
from cities c
where not exists (select 1 from people p where c.name = concat_ws(' ', p.name, p.lname);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried it, and it looks like it wasn't replacing the nulls with zeros, so I changed the first line to be `select p.ssn, ifnull(c.cityid, 0)` and it works!